# Count number of occourences of specific values in a string

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple rows with some words separeted by semicolons(;), and need to count how many times a certain word appears in Column A cell strings of Sheet1.

Using two rows for example:

```
Column "A"
Banana; Apple; Orange
Banana; Banana; Apple
```

I came up with this code for the counting of the specific word I want to count:

```
Sub count()

'The count will be registered in "B6"

strcount = "Banana"

For i = 2 to 30
    If InStr(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Text, strcount) <> 0 Then
     
       Cells(6, "B").Value = Cells(6, "B").Value + 1

    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

The problem with this code is that it doesn't recognize the 2 appearences of "Banana" in the second row returning me a count of 2 instead of 3:

```
Results for each fruit:
Banana: 2
Apple: 2
Orange: 1
```

I see that the problem is InStr only recognizes if the string is there, but how can I overcome this?

---

**Solution:**

Both basodre's and Алексей's answers worked.

For basodre's code I had to change only the delimiter from ";" to "; " (with a space after the semicolon) to match my string.

```
aFoods = Split(rIterator.Value, "; ")
```

Алексей's answer works perfectly too, but by the time of this edit is limited for Excel 2019 or above, given it uses the "TEXTJOIN" function and I couldn't come up with a replacement for that.

Comment: FYI this can be likely achieved without any code, using a pivot table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that I think does what you need. Please review, modify to your range, and let us know if it works.

```
Sub CountWords()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim aFoods As Variant
    Dim rIterator As Range
    Dim counter As Long
    
    Const theFood As String = "Banana"
    
    Set rng = Range("A1:A3")
    
    counter = 0
    For Each rIterator In rng
        aFoods = Split(rIterator.Value, ";")
        
        For i = LBound(aFoods) To UBound(aFoods)
            If aFoods(i) = theFood Then
                counter = counter + 1
            End If
        Next i
    Next rIterator
    
    Debug.Print counter
End Sub
```

Comment: Worth noting that `Filter()` matches on *substring* so "bread" and breadfruit" would both get counted as "bread"

Comment: @TimWilliams Good point. I updated the answer!

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm! The only modification i had to make is change the delimiter from ";" to "; " (with a space), as there is a space after each semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with RegExp:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test1()
    Dim re As Object, result As Object, text As String, fruit As Variant
    
    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    re.Global = True
        
    text = WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(";", True, Columns("A"))
    'In Excel < 2019 you can use: text = Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Intersect(Columns("A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)), ";")
    
For Each fruit In Array("Banana", "Apple", "Orange")
        re.Pattern = "\b" & fruit & "\b"
        Set result = re.Execute(text)
        Debug.Print "Amount of [" & fruit & "] = " & result.Count
    Next
End Sub
```

---

```
Output:  
Amount of [Banana] = 3  
Amount of [Apple] = 2  
Amount of [Orange] = 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately  i think the "TextJoin" function is only avaible in Excel 2019 or 365 and in my workplace I use 2010. Neverthless, I just tested on my personal computer with 365 and it worked!

I don't know if there is an alternative for older versions, but I'll note that!

Comment: In Excel < 2019 you can use `text = Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Intersect(Columns("A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)), ";")` instead the `TextJoin`

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expression

```vb
Sub FindEntries()
    Dim mc, rw
    Const word$ = "Banana"
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .IgnoreCase = True: .Global = True: .Pattern = "(^|;\s+)" & word & "(?=;|$)"
        For rw = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Set mc = .Execute(Cells(rw, "A")): [B6] = [B6] + mc.Count
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```